# items won't delete from localStorage with ES6

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I've been trying for hours to successfully remove items from a list through the localStorage API. I have no problem with inserting the items into the list and view them as they're being pushed into the view. How can I delete items from an array using localStorage? The code that I wrote is below. One other small issue, the form validation is not kicking in, I can't seem to spot the bug that's allowing null inputs.

index.html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="shoutout-box-pos">
                    <div class="shoutout-box">
                        <div class="shoutout-box-header">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <div class="shoutout-header-text">
                                    <h4>Post a shoutout</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="shoutout-form-container">
                                    <form id='shoutout-form'>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Name</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Customer Name" id="name" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Tell us about your stay!</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="What would you like to say?" id="message" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Which session did you take part in?</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="tour_session" placeholder="Give us the date or session title" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button class="bttn-bordered bttn-md bttn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Post Message</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="shoutout-messages">
                                    <ul class="messageListContainer" id="messageList">

                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

app.js

```
// ES6 Shoutout Messages
class Shoutout {
    constructor(name, message, tour_session) {
        this.name = name;
        this.message = message;
        this.tour_session = tour_session;
    }
}

class UI {
    addMessageToList(Shoutmessage) {
        const list = document.getElementById('messageList');
        // create li element
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        //Insert li into ul
        li.innerHTML = `
            <li><strong>Customer Name: </strong> <p class='lead'>${Shoutmessage.name}</p></li>
            <li><strong>Message: </strong> <p class='lead'> ${Shoutmessage.message}</p></li>
            <li><strong>Tour Session: </strong> <p class='lead'> ${Shoutmessage.tour_session} </p></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="delete bttn-minimal bttn-sm">Remove Shoutout<a></li>
        `;
        list.appendChild(li);
    }

    showAlert(message, className) {
        // create div
        const div = document.createElement('div');

        // Add classes
        div.className = `alert ${className}`;

        // Add text
        div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));

        // Get Parent Class
        const container = document.querySelector('.shoutout-form-container');

        // Get form Id
        const form = document.querySelector('#shoutout-form');

        // Insert alert
        container.insertBefore(div, form);

        // Timeout after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.querySelector('.alert').remove();
        }, 3000);
    }

    deleteShout(target) {
        if (target.className === 'delete') {
            target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    }

    clearFields() {
        document.getElementById('name').value = '';
        document.getElementById('message').value = '';
        document.getElementById('tour_session').value = '';
    }
}
// Local Storage Class Object
class Store {
    static getShoutouts() {
        let messages;
        if (localStorage.getItem('messages') === null) {
            messages = [];
        } else {
            messages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('messages'));
        }

        return messages;
    }

    static displayShoutouts() {
        const messages = Store.getShoutouts();
        messages.reverse().forEach(function (message) {
            const ui = new UI;

            ui.addMessageToList(message);
        });
    }

    static addMessage(message) {
        const messages = Store.getShoutouts();
        messages.push(message);

        localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messages));
    }

    static removeMessage(tour_session) {
        const messages = Store.getShoutouts();
        messages.forEach(function (message, index) {
            if (message.tour_session === tour_session) {
                messages.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
        localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(messages));
    }
}

// DOM Load Event
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Store.displayShoutouts);

// Event Listener for add message
document.getElementById('shoutout-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

    //Grab form values
    const name = document.getElementById('name').value,
        message = document.getElementById('message').value,
        tour_session = document.getElementById('tour_session').value

    // Instantiate message
    const msg = new Shoutout(name, message, tour_session);

    // Instantiate UI
    const ui = new UI();

    console.log(ui);

    // Validate
    if (name === '' || message === '' || tour_session === '') {
        //Error alert
        ui.showAlert('Please fil in all fields', 'error');
    } else {
        // Add message to list
        ui.addMessageToList(msg);

        // Add to Local Storage
        Store.addMessage(msg);

        // Show success
        ui.showAlert('Shoutout Message Added!', 'success');

        // Clear fields
        ui.clearFields();
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});


// Event Listener for delete

document.getElementById('messageList').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    // Instantiate UI
    const ui = new UI();

    // Delete message
    ui.deleteShout(e.target);

    // Remove from Local Storage
    Store.removeMessage(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent);

    // Show message
    ui.showAlert('Message Removed!', 'success');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: which code is attempting to remove from `localStorage`? I see `setItem` and `getItem` but no `removeItem` in your code!

Comment: I have a method in the showAlert that deletes the item from view. deleteShout(target) and I also have a removeMessage(tour_session) method in the store class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here in your code is that
`e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.textContent` probably returns string like 
*"Tour Session: ${tour_session}"*

while exact `tour session`, which you need, is inside the element in `p.lead`

so try to change your tour_session selector to

```
...
// Remove from Local Storage
Store.removeMessage(e.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.querySelector(".lead").textContent);
...
```

**UPD**

Take a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBEJZx?editors=1000).

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajpwYR?editors=0011

In your addMessageToList() method I've added an attribute `tour_session` to the Remove Shoutout link.

```js
addMessageToList(Shoutmessage) {
  const list = document.getElementById('messageList');
  // create li element
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  //Insert li into ul
  li.innerHTML = `
            <li><strong>Customer Name: </strong> <p class='lead'>${Shoutmessage.name}</p></li>
            <li><strong>Message: </strong> <p class='lead'> ${Shoutmessage.message}</p></li>
            <li><strong>Tour Session: </strong> <p class='lead'> ${Shoutmessage.tour_session} </p></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="delete bttn-minimal bttn-sm" tour_session=${Shoutmessage.tour_session}>Remove Shoutout<a></li>
        `;
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

In the event listener, pass the value of the tour_session attribute to the removeMessage method.

```js
document.getElementById('messageList').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Instantiate UI
  const ui = new UI();

  // Delete message
  ui.deleteShout(e.target);

  // Remove from Local Storage

  // console.log(e.target.getAttribute('tour_session'));
  Store.removeMessage(e.target.getAttribute('tour_session'));

  // Show message
  ui.showAlert('Message Removed!', 'success');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

In the deleteShout method, the className would return the names of all the classes you've specified. So, your check fails everytime and the node is not removed from the DOM.

```js
deleteShout(target) {
  if (target.className.split(' ').indexOf('delete') > -1) {
    target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
}
```